# Angular Doing lazyload but still have 1 main.js

Tags: javascript, angular, lazy-loading

1. app-routing
   https://prnt.sc/20zqxzy

```html
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "index" */ './pages/module/main/index-page/index-page.module').then(m => m.IndexPageModule)
  }, {
    path: 'user',
    loadChildren: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "user" */ './pages/module/user/user-routing/user-routing.module').then(m => m.UserRoutingModule)
  }
 ]
 
 
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    initialNavigation: 'enabledBlocking'
  })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

2. index-page-routing
   https://prnt.sc/20zr52z

```html
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { IndexPageComponent } from './index-page.component';

// Pages

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: IndexPageComponent,
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class IndexPageRoutingModule { }
```

But here when i build a project
https://prnt.sc/20zr994

It's have only main.js files and no have any lazy chunk files. what i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Check these modules for static import into any non lazy loaded module.(In most cases AppModule)